# refCount keeping connection even after an error

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rxandroidble, rx-kotlin

I'm using refCount to hold onto a BLE connection for 5 mins. This works well until I have a connection issue, refCount still keeps the connection and replay replays the error.

Is there a way I can make either make refCount disconnect as soon as there is an error, or make replay not replay errors?

```
        bleDevice
            .establishConnection(false)
            .replay(1)
            .refCount(1, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
```

Comment: Is having a timeout after which `.refCount()` will disconnect if no subscribers are present mandatory?

Comment: Which RxJava version do you have? 3.x should work as you expect.

Comment: Unfortunately RxAndroidBle is still 2.x based. This is planned to change.

Comment: @DariuszSeweryn The BT connection is slow to create (user to required to confirm connection on BT device), so for this particular device we would like to keep the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to achieve what you want is by using RxJava 3 `refCount` operator. You can use an RxJava 2 <=> 3 interoperability library [RxJavaBridge](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaBridge).

```
val connectionObservable = bleDevice
    .establishConnection(false)
    .`as`(RxJavaBridge.toV3Observable())
    .replay(1)
    .refCount(1, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .to(RxJavaBridge.toV2Observable()) // optional if you want to stick to RxJava 3
```